# Should the OP be able to review a post marked for review?

Tags: discussion, review

I recently posted a question. Today I noticed [one of the answers](https://superuser.com/a/1113581/623023) had a comment with a link to a review page. I didn't know Stack Exchange had a post review system, but I was annoyed to find that several people had marked the post as `Recommended Deletion`.

As the OP of the question, I felt this post was perfectly valid and attempted to answer my question as well as any of the other answers. Admittedly it's not particularly well-written, but a simple edit would fix that.

Should the OP of a question be able to make their own review of an answer to their question after the answer has been marked for review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a user with at least 15 reputation, you can upvote any post that you find helpful. Answers with a positive score can't be put into the low quality review queue, which makes it harder to delete them.

As someone with access to the Stack Exchange website, you can always¹ suggest an edit to a post. If a post isn't well-written and you care at all about that post, please improve it!

As the asker, you get notified when the answer is posted, so you get a chance of acting on it before others. Vote and edit as applicable.

It seems that you spotted a comment on that answer. If this comment is incorrect, you can leave a comment in reply, to explain why the answer is in fact worth keeping. As the asker, you can comment under any answer to your question even if you don't have enough reputation (50) to leave comments in general.

In addition, as the asker, you have the ability to mark one answer as accepted. Accepted answers can only be deleted by ♦ moderators.

I've seen too many cases where the asker commented something like “it doesn't work” and accepted the answer anyway to be comfortable with giving more power to the asker. Having truly worthwhile answers in the low quality review queue is uncommon in the first place, so I doubt that coding up exceptions for the asker would be worthwhile. And when it does happen, and the asker disagrees with relatively experienced users, I'd say it's a toss-up as to who is right.

¹  <sub>Offer void if prohibited by locking. Contents may not settle if another suggested edit is pending. Offer not available from some IP addresses due to spam filters. Minimum edit distance restrictions may apply. Consult your meta if the symptoms persist.</sub>

Comment: Fair enough. The smallprint made me laugh :P

Comment: Honestly not sure why I was downvoted, though. I was under the impression downvoting should be used on a question when the question was poorly asked or doesn't fit the site. Unless it's used differently on a `Discussion` meta question, does my question not belong on this site?

Comment: @Clonkex On meta downvotes on question often mean “I disagree”. In theory this should only be done with explicit [meta-tag:feature-request] questions, but your question is framed as a feature request despite the [meta-tag:discussion] tag, and I suspect that several people downvoted because they disagreed with your specific proposal and not because they found your meta question badly asked or even because they found your concern unreasonable.

Comment: Cool that makes sense :)